# Add to Cart Button Disappeared CSS issue?

Tags: html, css, shopify

The add to cart button code is in there source, but it's not visible.  I'm pretty sure it's a CSS thing and was hoping for some eyes to see if they could tell why.  The page is https://ragsdev.myshopify.com/collections/new-releases/products/short-sleeve-rag-rags

```
                <div class="ProductAdd">
                    <div class="input-wrapper ProductAdd__button">
                        <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="button button--buy is-disabled" disabled="" style="background-color: rgb(19, 111, 153);">Make a selection</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

It shows up in the backend, not the live site

Comment: You clearly haven't even tried.

Comment: I see it, so maybe it's a browser incompatibility? https://s1.postimg.org/5se61d7uvz/92_F5_ACD6-41_B1-4_F02-_A0_F1-4_F3554_CBEF40.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a piece of code you have that reads:

```
form[action='/cart/add'] input[type=submit], form[action='/cart/add'] button[type=submit], .easylockdown-hidden-purchase{
 display: none;
}
```

You'll need to remove the [/cart/add] parts of that

---

---

Comment: Aid to your answer: CSS in question: https://ragsdev.myshopify.com/collections/new-releases/products/short-sleeve-rag-rags

Comment: The button is also `disabled`